# How to filter collection by array elements

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am having array in following format

```
"categories": [
  {
     "type": "A",               
     "subtype": [
        "X",
        "Y",
        "Z",
        "D",
         "E"           
     ],

  },
  {
     "type": "B",
     "Subtypes": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5"
     ],        
  },
  {
     "type": "C",         
     "includeConnectionTypes": [
        "@",
        "#",
        "$"
     ],
}]
```

I am having 2nd array array B

```
B = ["C","A"]
```

now how to filter elements in category array based on elements in array B

Comment: A[t].type===B[i]?....... this is your needed?

Comment: you can read about [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: is there any lodash function to do the same?

Comment: @POM ... as for *lodash* based solutions see Kai's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951620/how-to-filter-collection-by-array-elements/#46951756) and the [2nd approach of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46951620/how-to-filter-collection-by-array-elements/#46952343).

Comment: @POM I just update my answer for more correct ;)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need: `_.filter`.

```
_.filter(categories, (item => B.indexOf(item.type)>= 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

**ES5**

```
var result = categories.filter(function (item) {
    return B.indexOf(item.type) > -1;    
});
```

**ES6**

```
var result = categories.filter(item => B.indexOf(item.type) > -1);
```

This statement will check each element of "categories" array, if its type is an element of array B, it will be pushed to "result" array.

"indexOf" method returns the index of an element in an array, and if that array does not contain that element, this method will return -1.

Reference: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1):

```
var categories=[
  {
     "type": "A",               
     "subtype": [
        "X",
        "Y",
        "Z",
        "D",
         "E"           
     ],

  },
  {
     "type": "B",
     "Subtypes": [
        "0",
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "5"
     ],        
  },
  {
     "type": "C",         
     "includeConnectionTypes": [
        "@",
        "#",
        "$"
     ],
}];
```

It is a array,Now B is also array

```
var B = ["C","A"]

 var result=categories.filter(function(d){
    return B.indexOf(d.type)!=-1;
 });
```

"result" contains your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `Array.prototype.filter` and the bound usage of `Array.prototype.some` should make a well readable approach that also has the advantage of code-reuse via a sole specific function like `doesCategoryTypeMatchAnyBoundType` that, unlike the other approaches/solutions which do combine `filter` and `indexOf`, does not need to "know" the reference of the filter type list (there `B` from the given example).

```js
// Q: I am having array in following format ...

var categories = [{
  "type": "A",
  "subtype": ["X", "Y", "Z", "D", "E"]
}, {
  "type": "B",
  "Subtypes": ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
}, {
  "type": "C",
  "includeConnectionTypes": ["@", "#", "$"]
}];

// ... I am having 2nd array array ...

var typeList = ["C","A"];

// ... now how to filter elements in category array based on
// elements in ... `typeList` ... array ...


// A: a combination of `Array.prototype.filter` and
// the bound usage of `Array.prototype.some` should make
// a well readable approach ...

function doesCategoryTypeMatchAnyBoundType(categoryItem) {
  return this.some(function (type) { return (categoryItem.type === type); });
}

var filteredCategoryList = categories.filter(doesCategoryTypeMatchAnyBoundType, typeList);

console.log("filteredCategoryList : ", filteredCategoryList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

> is there any lodash function to do the same?

Try sticking with the language core as long as you can. But if you are forced to use *lodash*, the just provided approach would change to ...

```js
var categories = [{
  "type": "A",
  "subtype": ["X", "Y", "Z", "D", "E"]
}, {
  "type": "B",
  "Subtypes": ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
}, {
  "type": "C",
  "includeConnectionTypes": ["@", "#", "$"]
}];

var typeList = ["C","A"];


function doesCategoryTypeMatchAnyBoundType(categoryItem) {
  return _.some(this, function (type) { return (categoryItem.type === type); });
}

var filteredCategoryList = _.filter(categories, doesCategoryTypeMatchAnyBoundType.bind(typeList));

console.log("filteredCategoryList : ", filteredCategoryList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```